# Change text and size of the "remember me" checkbox on woocommercelogin form

Tags: css, checkbox, woocommerce

1. change text of the label of "remember me" checkbox
2. Change the size of the checkbox

for 1 I tried this code

I tried this code ,but doesnt work

```
    $translated = str_ireplace('RECUÉRDAME',  'Recordarme',  $translated);
    return $translated;
}
add_filter(  'gettext',  'rememberme_text'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'rememberme_text'  );
```

To changing the size of the checkbox , I tryed :

.woocommerce-account input:not([type='submit']){height: 30px;
    width: 20%;}

But this doesnt work because it also change me the size of others part of the form, and im only trying to make the checkbox smaller

Here is the page
https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/my-account/

Answer (score 0):

you only need to change the height based on the page you provided.